# Channel form entry status always set to closed

Tags: safecracker, status, saef

I have a site that I recently upgraded, and converted a safecracker form to a channel form. Since the upgrade, every entry posted through the form has its status set to closed, no matter what the status field is set to in the form. I use the same form for editing, and I am able to edit an existing entry and change the status, but EE seems to be ignoring the status set via the form when the entry is created.

I have custom status set up for the channel, and have 'held' set as the channel default. I tried stripping out the status field entirely, and adding

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="held" />
```

but that didn't change anything.

The channel has my custom status group assigned to it, and all members have access to my custom statuses.

It doesn't matter whether I'm logged in as a regular member or a superadmin, new entries posted through the channel form always have the status set to closed.

Is there some way around this? Relevant form code is below:

```
{exp:channel:form 
 channel="calendar_events" 
 include_assets="no"
 use_live_url="no"
 return="schedule/appointment/confirm/{if segment_4 ==     "edit"}edit/{/if}ENTRY_ID"
 {if segment_4 == "edit"}entry_id="{last_segment}"{/if}
 logged_out_member_id="6"
 rules:appointment-time="required"
 }    
{!-- Set Entry Status --}
<!-- {status} -->
<dt><label for="status">Status</label></dt>
<dd><select name="status" id="status">
  <option value="Held" {if status == "Held"}selected{/if}>Hold</option>
  <option value="Booked" {if status == "Booked"}selected{/if}>Book</option>
  {if logged_in_group_id == "1" OR logged_in_group_id == "7"}
  <option value="open" {if status == "open"}selected{/if}>Delete</option>
  <option value="closed" {if status == "closed"}selected{/if}>Closed</option>
  {/if}
</select></dd>
</dl>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally missed the new Channel Form Settings admin panel. Once I set the default status there, everything works fine.